# How to avoid social networks visiting my English version of the web?

Tags: php, html, facebook, .htaccess, twitter

I have a website with two versions: the one which is in English and the Spanish one. And I control whether the visitors access one or the other through.htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Inglés 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ en/home [R,NC,L]

#Español
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ es/inicio [R,NC,L]

#General
RewriteRule ^/?$ en/home [R,NC,L]
```

The problem is that, when promoting the site on social networks in Spanish, they access to the English version of the site, and so that they show the "preview"'s attributes, such as title and description, (summary card on Twitter, for example) of the Web in English. I want to prevent that so that they load the Spanish content of the Web. Do you have an idea about how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I decided to change only the og:url meta tag in order to get the Spanish previews, while preserving the English versions of og:description so that if visitors share the website being inside, get a localized version. That did the trick!